# Media Tailor ad returning 504 error in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-504, aws-mediatailor

I'm using AWS Media Tailor to test an ad inserting demo. The demo page is this one: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-media-services-simple-vod-workflow/tree/master/12-AdMarkerInsertion.

When I place my manifest into a TheoPlayer I always get an `504` error. My manifes page is: https://ebf348c58b834d189af82777f4f742a6.mediatailor.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/master/3c879a81c14534e13d0b39aac4479d6d57e7c462/MyTestCampaign/llama.m3u8.

I have also tried with: https://ebf348c58b834d189af82777f4f742a6.mediatailor.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/master/3c879a81c14534e13d0b39aac4479d6d57e7c462/MyTestCampaign/llama_with_slates.m3u8.

The specific error is:

```
{"message":"failed to generate manifest: Unable to obtain template playlist. sessionId:[c915d529-3527-4e37-89e0-087e393e75de]"}
```

I have read about this error: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/playback-errors-examples.html

But don't know how to fix it.

Maybe I did something wrong or do I need a quote in AWS?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inquiry!

> The following example shows the result when a timeout occurs between AWS Elemental MediaTailor and either the ad decision server (ADS) or the origin server.

An HTTP 504 error is known as a Gateway Timeout meaning that a resource was unresponsive and prevented the request from completing successfully. In this case since MediaTailor is returning an HTTP 504 this means that either the ADS or Origin failed to respond within the timeout period.

To troubleshoot this you will need to determine which dependency is failing to respond to MediaTailor and correct it. Typically the issue is the ADS failing to respond to a VAST request performed by MediaTailor which you can confirm by reviewing your CloudWatch logs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/monitor-cloudwatch-ads-logs.html

Make sure that your ADS follows the guidelines listed below for integrating with MediaTailor.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediatailor/latest/ug/vast-integration.html